# How to output lines as connected points

Tags: qgis

I have lines which I want to output as connected points. So What I would like is:

```
point  x  y
p1    20 30
p2    30 40
p3    50 40
```

and:

```
Line point1 point2
l1   p1     p2
l2   p1     p3
```

I do not see how to extract this from the line layer I have. I have managed to extract points from these line but as far as I can judge I then lose the information on how to connect all of them (which is NOT simply connecting all points to all points or connecting it to the closest one) There is a specific way they should be connected.

I am quite sure this information could be extracted from QGIS but I do not really know how.

Comment: You want to connect p1 with all others? p1-p2 p1-p3 p1-p4 etc?

Comment: no this is just an example. The lines represent paths which can have endpoints and triple junctions.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the data you have with attribute table?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the algorithm 'extract vertices' to extract the 'points' of the line.

For example: I have a layer with 3 lines

[image]

Execute the algorithm 'extract vertices'

This is the result:

[image]

Now you can add X and Y to the table using the fieldcalculator:

[image]

With this as result:

[image]

Meaning of the fields:

- fid: line-id
- vertex_index: order of the vertex along the line
- distance: distance from the previous vertex
- X: x-coordinate calculated by the fieldcalculator with expression `$x`
- Y: y-coordinate calculated by the fieldcalculator with expression `$y`

If you export the results as a spreadsheet (eg. excel) you can use a pivot-table to reorder the results